# Using AWS Amplify Auth on the server with custom auth-storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a server side rendered react application, that invokes Amplify's `Auth.CurrentAuthenticatedUser` method to check for auth before displaying protected pages. 
On the client side I'm using `cookieStorage`. It works perfectly fine as the credentials are retrieved successfully when invoking `Auth.CurrentAuthenticatedUser` upon accessing protected routes via react-router's `BrowserRouter`. 
On the server-side (when the protected routes are accessed by a direct http call), I'm using the following configuration for Amplify:

```
import cookie from 'cookie';

class ServerCookieStorage {
  constructor(requestCookie) {
    this.cookieObj = {};
    if (requestCookie) this.cookieObj = cookie.parse(requestCookie);
  }
  setItem(key, value) {
    this.cookieObj[key] = value;
  }
  getItem(key) {
    return this.cookieObj[key];
  }
  removeItem(key) {
    this.cookieObj[key] = '';
  }
}

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    identityPoolId: 'placeholder',
      region: 'placeholder',
      userPoolId: 'placeholder',
      userPoolWebClientId: 'placeholder',
      storage: new ServerCookieStorage(event.headers.Cookie);
      //cookie header in aws lambda functions is located in event.header.Cookie
  }
});
```

I've logged what goes into the `setItem` and `getItem` methods and it seems to be retrieving all the information fine when the `Auth.CurrentAuthenticatedUser` method is invoked, however the method is failing with the error `Not Authenticated`.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You could also just use `CookieStorage`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62646354/5874913

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realised that the `Auth.CurrentAuthenticatedUser` uses the `fetch` method under the hood, which is why it was failing. The solution was to provide a `fetch` method polyfill for node using `node-fetch`, I did it like so:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
global.fetch = fetch;
```