# Check if the user is authenticated on the initial request

Tags: nuxt.js, amazon-cognito, server-side-rendering, aws-amplify

I am using nuxt + aws amplify for the web app and I need to check if the user is authenticated to load the page details depending on that. I configured amplify so the user credentials are stored in the cookie instead of the local storage so all the information about the user can be retrieved from `req.headers.cookie`, but the code below

```js
async nuxtServerInit (props, ctx) {
  const { Auth } = withSSRContext(ctx)
  try {
    const cognitoUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
    console.log(cognitoUser)
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
},
```

gives `The user is not authenticated`

My amplify config:

```js
Amplify.configure({
    sst: true,
    Auth: {
        identityPoolId: process.env.IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
        userPoolId: process.env.USER_POOL_ID,
        userPoolWebClientId: process.env.USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID,
        region: 'eu-central-1',
        mandatorySignIn: false,
        cookieStorage: {
            domain: isDev ? 'localhost;' : '.website.my',
            path: '/',
            expires: 1,
            sameSite: 'strict',
            secure: !isDev
        },
        authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH'
    }
})
```

Login and auth work fine on client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the issue was in the configuration, when using `ssr: true` you are not allowed to add manual configuration for cookies.
So the solution here is just removing this block

```
cookieStorage: {
  domain: isDev ? 'localhost;' : '.website.my',
  path: '/',
  expires: 1,
  sameSite: 'strict',
  secure: !isDev
},
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've configured Amplify correctly. I'd recommend going through the following guides and double check your configuration...

1. https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/data-model/q/integration/next#api-with-server-side-rendering-ssr
2. [AWS Cognito cookie storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59409205/aws-cognito-cookie-storage)
3. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1735